# Can't Display KML file in Google earth

Tags: google-earth, android, google-earth-pro

I am unable to display a kmz/kml file on Google Earth on Android. I got the file from here:
ftp://ecco2.jpl.nasa.gov/data5/GoogleEarth/Ocean%20Currents.kmz

I tried using KMZ to Earth Explorer.
I've put the files on Google Drive and imported them in Google Earth.
Either way, I just get a "blank" earth. I can see it correctly on Google Earth Pro on my PC.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I'm confused - is it Earth Explorer or Google Earth that you're having trouble opening the file?

Comment: I see your confusion ... and mine. I mean Google Earth. I misread the functionally of the KMZ to Earth Explorer.

Comment: Are you having trouble opened the KMZ in Google Earth for Android?  So it works fine when you try it on PC?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your Google Earth on Android to the new version (9.x) of Google Earth, which came out in April. It has better KML support. Worked for me.